# Chef Inspec on 32 bit Windows 2008 servers

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

We want to Scan our **32 bit Windows 2008** servers using Inspec. But Chef doesn't have a Inspec Client for this version of Windows.

Is there a way we can use Inspec in our environment?

Cheers

Comment: Which version of chefdk/inspec are you using?

Comment: I don't have any preferences. Any chefdk or inspec version should be good to get started.

Comment: See https://github.com/chef/inspec/issues/2011 if this helps

Answer (score 1):

The InSpec client is run from a workstation or compliance analysis server. You don't install it on the target being scanned (unlike Chef, which uses a more traditional agent model). That said, a lot of stuff might not work unless you install newer versions of Powershell and whatnot, and I'm not entirely sure they support such old versions of WinRM.